# Minimum number of operations

Tags: optimization

We have a sequence $A$ of size $n$, where each element $A_i \in \{-1,0,1\}$. In each operation we can increase $A_{i+1}$ by $A_i$. The goal is to make the sequence non-decreasing i.e. $A_1 \leq A_2 \leq \dots \leq A_n $ with the minimum number of operations. Assume that $A$ is a sequence which can be always made non decreasingly.

Is my assumption true, that at the end of all operations, every element $A_i \in \{-1,0,1\}$? And if yes, how do we prove it?

Comment: Suppose $A_1=A_2=\cdots=A_{n-1}=0$, and $A_n=-1$.  How do you make this non-decreasing using these operations?

Comment: My apology. I should have told you that you must assume that the sequence can be made non decreasingly.